# How very odd, Unity sprite render works on some images but not others

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, photoshop

Here's the error.

```
ArgumentException: Could not create sprite (0.000000, 0.000000, 750.000000, 346.000000) from a 500x332 texture.

UnityEngine.Sprite.Create (UnityEngine.Texture2D texture, Rect rect, Vector2 pivot) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/SpritesBindings.gen.cs:89)

dynamicScrollingList.saveImage (System.String path, System.Byte[] imageBytes, UnityEngine.GameObject thispanel) (at Assets/Scripts/Toolkit/dynamicScrollingList.cs:183)
```

I'm editing images in photoshop, saving as a jpg or png then uploading to wordpress, the images are then pulled via www request into unity and assigned to a texture.

It was all working fine until today when I uploaded a different jpg for a logo.  Nothing special about it, it seems that when I edit in photoshop and then upload they don't work, however if I pull a random image from google and upload it they pull in and are assigned to the texture in unity successfully.

Here's the unity / monodevelop

```
byte[] imageBytes = loadImage(savePath);
                        //Loaded so assign it
                        Texture2D texture;
                        texture = new Texture2D(750, 346);
                        texture.LoadImage(imageBytes);
                        Image im = imagePanelItem.GetComponent<Image>();
                        im.sprite = Sprite.Create (texture, new Rect (0, 0, 750, 346), new Vector2 ());//set the Rect with position and dimensions as you need.
```

It works with some of my edited photos but not others, do you know what I'm doing wrong in the process?  Are there any issues with assigning jpgs or pngs to textures if they aren't saved in a magical way or something.

Very odd.  Help appreciated.

Comment: What is the url of the image and how are you downloading it? Post post you use to download it. Those are two possible problems here.

Comment: I got it working but still need help, it turns out the image I uploaded was 500px in width, and I'm assigning it to a texture with a 750 width, if I upload a bigger version (http://www.cielo.cat/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/DSC_2760.jpg).

    It works.  Do you know what I can add to my c# code to cater for smaller images without throwing an exception and scaling the image to fit on the texture please.  Thanks for the fast initial response by the way.

Comment: If you got it working, it shouldn't throw an exception. Until you put your downloading code, I have no idea how to help you.